# if $X \in \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ is any nilpotent element, then the adjoint action $\operatorname{ad}(X)$ is nilpotent

Tags: lie-algebras, nilpotence

I found a observation in the beginning of the proof of Engel's Theorem in the Fulton's book "Representation Theory"

Observation: if $X \in \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ is any nilpotent element, then the action $\operatorname{ad}(X):\mathfrak{gl}(V) \to \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ is nilpotent. This is straightforward: to say that $X$ is nilpotent is to say that there exist a flag of a subspaces: $0 \subset V_1 \subset V_2 ... \subset V_{k+1}=V$ such that $X(V_i) \subset V_{i-1}$; we can then check that for any endomorphism $Y$ of $V$ the endomorphism $\operatorname{ad}(X)^m (Y)$ carries $V_i$ into $V_{i+k-m}$.

Is this index $i+k-m$ correct? I tried to check the last sentence, but I can't.

Comment: I don't immediately see why this is true. But, for a different proof, write $\operatorname{ad} X$ as $L_X - R_X$, where $L_X : \mathfrak{gl}\left(V\right) \to \mathfrak{gl}\left(V\right)$ sends every $U$ to $XU$, and where $R_X : \mathfrak{gl}\left(V\right) \to \mathfrak{gl}\left(V\right)$ sends every $U$ to $UX$. The endomorphisms $L_X$ and $R_X$ are commute and are nilpotent. If two nilpotent elements of a ring commute, then their difference is nilpotent (why?).

Comment: To help future viewers, expanding on darij's hint, consider the binomial expansion of $\text{ad} X$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg However, $L_X$ and $R_X$ are not endomorphisms of the $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$, right? (But their difference is.) It doesn't really matter, though, since we only need the nilpotency (and $\operatorname{ad}(X)$ is indeed an endomorphism of $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$).

Comment: @richrow: They are vector space endomorphisms, not Lie algebra endomorphisms.